# While Google's SMS one-time code autofill service, what does API_NOT_AVAILABLE status mean?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, autofill, android-autofill-manager

I am trying to implement SMS one-time code autofill service.

```
        SmsCodeAutofillClient smsCodeAutofillClient = SmsCodeRetriever.getAutofillClient(this);
        Task<Void> voidTask = smsCodeAutofillClient.startSmsCodeRetriever();
```

Everytime, this task is running into failure with the following exception:
"com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 36501" and the status message as API_NOT_AVAILABLE.
Google [doc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/phone/SmsRetrieverStatusCodes#API_NOT_AVAILABLE) says the following regarding this status:

> The calling application is not eligible to use this particular API.
>
> Note: For SmsCodeAutofillClient, this status indicates that the
>   calling application is not the current user-designated autofill
>   service.

My question is what does this exception mean actually? What does it mean by "the calling application is not the current user-designated autofill service" ?

Answer (score 0):

That means your app has to be an [Autofill service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-services) app, besides, it needs to be selected as the device's default autofill service app, see [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/788571/how-to-change-your-autofill-and-password-manager-on-android/) for the reference.

The above is the prerequisite of using this API.